# bash, expect password is no passing in

Tags: bash, passwords, expect, scp, spawn

I'm trying to use scp, there is no key for the box I need to communicate w/.
I tried this code and many variations of it from my searches online, for some reason it doesn't get entered in.
If you can help me it would be great.  Thanks in advance.
BTW, I'm executing the bash script from testing on a mac.

```
#!/bin/bash

#$1- source file
#$2- destination
#$3- password

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn scp -rp $1  $2
set pass $3
expect -re "password:"
send "password\r" 
expect "\r"
send "\r\n"
EOF
```

result is ;

```
spawn scp -rp file1 user@x.com:/path/file2
me@whoknows.com's password: 
return value was : 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I assume that is to be used inside the expect, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the `end of file (eof)` of the `scp` command

```
#!/bin/bash

#$1- source file
#$2- destination
#$3- password

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn scp -rp $1  $2
set pass $3; # Instead, you can also directly use the '$3' for password
puts "pwd = \$pass"
expect -re "password:"
send "\$pass\r" 
expect eof
EOF
```

**Output :**

```
dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:~/stackoverflow$ ./vmaxer srcfile dinesh@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/dinesh welcome!2E
spawn scp -rp srcfile dsivaji@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/dinesh
pwd = welcome!2E
dinesh@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx's password: 
srcfile                                                        100%  281     0.3KB/s   00:00    
dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:~/stackoverflow$
```

**Note :** If your file is too big and takes more time than `Expect`'s default timeout (which is 10 seconds), you should increase the `timeout` value.

It can be achieved as,

```
set timeout 60; # This will make the timeout value to '1 min'
```

Comment: Yes the file is pretty big 23M to be exact.  Should I also use an interact statement?

Comment: `interact ` not needed. As mentioned, increase the `timeout` value